# Force clang to generate intrinsic cos

Tags: clang, llvm, intrinsics, trigonometry

Compile `cos.c`

```
void func() {
    double a = __builtin_cos(3.0);
}
```

using

```
clang -S -emit-llvm -c cos.c
```

I've got

```
define dso_local void @func() {
  %1 = alloca double, align 8
  %2 = call double @cos(double 3.000000e+00)
  store double %2, double* %1, align 8
  ret void
}


declare dso_local double @cos(double)
```

But I want to obtain the llvm intrinsics `@llvm.fcos.f64` for `cos` instead of `@cos`, i.e. the generated code should be like that

```
  ...
  %2 = call double @llvm.fcos.f64(double 3.000000e+00)
  ...
}

declare double @llvm.cos.f64(double)
```

How can I force `clang` to do that? Maybe I should use another function instead of `__builtin_cos`?

Comment: I thought maybe we could get it by telling clang to compile for 32-bit x86 without SSE, so it might inline `cos` as the x87 `fcos` instruction.  (Is that what LLVM `fcos.f64` is?)  But no, it still wants to call library `cos()`.  https://godbolt.org/z/Z70ug0 even with `-O3 -ffast-math -m32 -mno-sse`  (for a runtime-variable function arg, so it can't constant-propagate through `cos` and just return a constant.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I think using `__builtin_cos` is not good, since this function has side effect (it sets `errno` code)

Comment: `-ffast-math` should include `-fno-math-errno`.  (It does for GCC, but I'm not as familiar with clang.)

Comment: @PeterCordes could you please push your comment as answer, because it's correct: `-ffast-math` forces `clang` generate `@llvm.cos.f64`. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: My first comment was wrong, turns out I had the right answer but didn't read carefully enough, oops!  (I usually only look at x86 asm, not LLVM-IR).  Didn't need to force 32-bit no-sse after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With `-ffast-math` (which implies `-fno-math-errno`)**, clang `-O3` will inline `__builtin_cos` to `@llvm.cos.f64`

```
double func(double in) {
    double a = __builtin_cos(in);
    return a;
}
```

`clang -O3 -ffast-math -emit-llvm` [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'double+func(double+in)+%7B%0A++++double+a+%3D+__builtin_cos(in)%3B%0A++++return+a%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:51.80156657963446,l:'4',m:99.99999999999999,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang700,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'1',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-ffast-math+-Wall+-emit-llvm',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+7.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:76.4,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+7.0.0',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:23.599999999999998,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:48.19843342036554,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) (with debug stuff removed)

```
define dso_local double @_Z4funcd(double) local_unnamed_addr #0 !dbg !7 {
  %2 = tail call fast double @llvm.cos.f64(double %0), !dbg !15
  ret double %2, !dbg !17
}
```